# Next.js 14 cache revalidation not working with dynamic segment

Tags: next.js, vercel

In our website all paths are static except one path which has dynamic segment, we're generating all the segments when building. We're using manual revalidation with `revalidatePath` in (api) route handler, like: `revalidatePath('/', 'layout');`
Unfortunately dynamic segments doesn't updates.

Lets prepare the re-production step.
Lets think that we've categories in the api (different backend app, hosted somewhere else), which is **cat1, cat2, cat3**. This are dynamic data & can change anytime but usually doesn't change often.

We're using this categories as as dynamic segment in Next.js like: `/cat/[catName]`

Following is the workflow which produces this.

1. Deploy site in vercel.
2. Update first category to `cat11`
3. Trigger manual (full) revalidation using `revalidatePath('/', 'layout');`
4. Visit the route which is changed in #2 (`/cat/cat11`) &  it's showing 404 page

How to re-validate this?